# Delphi Saving open office document as PDF

Tags: delphi

I am using the following code to export an Open Office document as a pdf file using Delphi:

```
procedure TOOoWriter.SaveToPDF(FileName: string);
var
   wProperties: variant;
begin
   if not (fConnected and fDocumentOpened) then
      abort;

   wProperties := VarArrayCreate([0, 3], varVariant);
   if fHTMLSrc then
      wProperties[0] := MakePropertyValue('FilterName', 'writer_web_pdf_Export')
   else
      wProperties[0] := MakePropertyValue('FilterName', 'writer_pdf_Export');

   wProperties[1] := MakePropertyValue('CompressionMode', '1');
   wProperties[2] := MakePropertyValue('Pages', 'All');
   wProperties[3] := MakePropertyValue('Overwrite', TRUE);

   fDocument.StoreToURL('file:///'+ StringReplace(FileName, '\', '/', [rfIgnoreCase, rfReplaceAll]), wProperties);
end;
```

All is working well except:

1. it insists on opening the resultant pdf file (but not the OO file).  This is problematic because I will be writing 100s of files without user interaction.
2. if the output pdf file does not exist I get an exception, but the file is created properly.  The second time it works ok as the file was created the first time.

Are there solutions to these problems?

Comment: With code from [`this post`](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7819626/960757) I haven't noticed any of the problems you describe.

Comment: Is this using COM? I don't know about OpenOffice - which has been eclipsed by LibreOffice for some time now - but LibreOffice has a command-line option that can convert between any files it can read/write, including PDF, like so: http://kgsspot.blogspot.com/2011/09/convert-doc-to-pdf-in-command-line.html

Comment: @alcalde, yes, it is based on OLE automation. Out of curiosity, when you have mentioned LibreOffice, its API should be compatible with OpenOffice, so the code should be portable.

Comment: Thanks for the comments.  TLama, I had previously looked at the post you linked to, but hadn't seen anything significant.  Interesting to know that you don't see the problems I see, so I will try that code out.  Incidently, I am using Libra Office.  I mentioned Open Office as most searches I've done refer to the OO api.

Comment: To update ... there is an option "View PDF after export" on the PDF Export dialog in Libra Office.  With this not selected everything works fine.  Selecting it I get the two problems described above.  I just have to find the way to deselect in code, now.