# Delphi Open Office / Libre Office PDF export selecting pages to print

Tags: delphi, pdf, export, delphi-6

I am using the code from this post:

[Delphi Saving open office document as PDF](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22019000/delphi-saving-open-office-document-as-pdf)

to export a Libre Office Writer document as a PDF file.

I am trying to print only the first page of a 2 page document.

I have changed the "pages" property line to:

```
wProperties[2] := MakePropertyValue('Pages', '1');
```

and

```
wProperties[2] := MakePropertyValue('Pages', 1);
```

Neither work.

I have seen this page:

https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/API/Tutorials/PDF_export

where another property is mentioned, namely PageRange.

This doesn't seem to work either.

What am I doing wrong?  Is it possible to select a specific page to print like this?

I am using Delphi 6 if it matters.

Update:
When I say that the things I've tried haven't worked, what I get exported is a pdf file with all pages included.  Its as if the parameters I've added were not there at all.

Comment: You should include a concise repro and details of how your code fails. "Neither work" is not enough.

Comment: @DH - thanks David, good thinking. I've updated the question.